# Animating straight SVG path into curved?

Tags: animation, svg, path, transition

I have two SVG's, both made out of 3 lines.

In the first SVG the lines are straight:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1000 521.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 521.8;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:106;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M0,261.9h77c27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0h823"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,261.9h77c27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0h823"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M0,463.9h77c27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0h823"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,463.9h77c27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0h823"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,59.9h77c27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0h823"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

and in the second one I have the same three lines but just braided together:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 1000 521.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1000 521.8;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
 .st1{fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:106;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M0,261.9h77c27.5,0,71.7-5.9,98.3-13.1L825.7,72.9c26.5-7.2,70.8-13.1,98.3-13.1h76"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,261.9h77c27.5,0,71.7-5.9,98.3-13.1L825.7,72.9c26.5-7.2,70.8-13.1,98.3-13.1h76"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st0" d="M0,463.9h77c27.5,0,71.7-5.9,98.3-13.1l650.5-175.9c26.5-7.2,70.8-13.1,98.3-13.1h76"/>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,463.9h77c27.5,0,71.7-5.9,98.3-13.1l650.5-175.9c26.5-7.2,70.8-13.1,98.3-13.1h76"/>
</g>
<g>
 <path class="st1" d="M0,59.9h77c27.5,0,69.8,10.7,94,23.8l660,356.5c24.2,13.1,66.5,23.8,94,23.8h75"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm wondering if there is some kind of transition feature? Or how else it would work

Comment: You've asked this question three times now. Why do you keep deleting this question and re-asking it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. There are plenty of examples online (and on this site).  Search for "svg path tweening" or "svg path morphing".

The important rule to know is that the original line and the final line have to have the same set of path commands, in the same order. At the moment your original lines have "Mhch", but your braided lines are "MhcLch".

```
Original: M 0,261.9
          h 77
          c 27.5,0,72.5,0,100,0
          h 823

Final:    M 0,261.9
          h 77
          c 27.5,0,71.7-5.9,98.3-13.1
          L 825.7,72.9
          c 26.5-7.2,70.8-13.1,98.3-13.1
          h 76
```

In order for animation of the `d` attribute to work. You'll need to change the original paths so that the are also "MhcLch".